# How to write each part of a file in a seperate directory?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a file (name:`state2`) with the following structure:

```
timestep
  0.0000000      0.0000000      0.0000000
  0.0000000      0.0000000      1.2176673
timestep
 -0.0151405     -0.0000000     -0.0874954
 -0.0347223      0.0000001      1.2559323
timestep
 -0.0492274      0.0000001     -0.1238961
 -0.0976473     -0.0000002      1.2335932
.... (24 timesteps)
```

I am trying to put each `timestep` (only numbers) in a separate file within a directory. I have written the following code but it only writes the first timestep data into a file. If I remove the `break`, then it will write the whole original file again into separate files.

```
import os

steps = []
BaseDir=os.getcwd()
data=os.path.join(BaseDir, 'state2')
f= open(data, 'r')
all_lines = f.readlines()
for k in range(24):
    path = os.path.join(BaseDir, 'steps_{0:01d}'.format(k))
    os.mkdir(path)
    dest = os.path.join(BaseDir,'steps_{0:01d}'.format(k), 'step{0:01d}'.format(k))
    fout = open(dest, 'w')
    for i in range(0, len(all_lines)):
        if 'timestep' in all_lines[i]:
           fout.write('{0}{1}}'.format(all_lines[i+1], all_lines[i+2]))
           break
```

Comment: Does each timestep have the same number of lines?

Comment: yes each timestep have the same number of lines

Comment: Step through your code carefully. What happens when you loop over `for i in range(0, len(all_lines)` each time? Anyways Pranav's answer has the right idea.

Comment: @Sophi, I think there is some confusion in the format of the original input file. Can you please confirm that your `state2` file looks like what I have edited it to? i.e. it does not have blank lines between two lines of numbers?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, Yes, your modification is correct. there is no blank line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the nested `for` with the `if` and `break` shenanigans. All you need to do is:

- Iterate through the lines in your original file.

  1. When you see "timestep", open a new file to write in and move on to the next line.
  2. If you don't see "timestep", write the line to the current file and move on to the next line.

```
fout = None
timestepnum = 0
for line in all_lines:
    if line == "timestep": # Or whatever condition you identify
        # this line says timestep, so we have now started looking at a new timestep (condition 1)
        if fout is not None:
           fout.close() # close the old timestep's file if it is already open
        
        timestepnum += 1

        # make the directory
        path = os.path.join(BaseDir, 'steps_{0:01d}'.format(timestepnum))
        os.mkdir(path)

        # open the file
        filename = os.path.join(BaseDir, f"steps_{timestepnum:01d}", f"step{timestepnum:01d}") # Code to specify file name
        fout = open(filename, 'w')

    elif fout is not None:
        # Condition 2 -- write this line as-is to the file.
        fout.write(line)
```

Comment: please rollback your edit on OP's question. You have removed the line breaks between the lines in the `state2` file... Those where probably intentional and part of the file... (or atleast add the line breaks back)

Comment: @Yatin, since OP is writing `all_lines[i+1], all_lines[i+2]` in their original code, it stands to reason that there isn't an empty line between two lines of data. The line breaks were there from when OP hadn't formatted that part of the question and needed to add two newlines to get SO's markdown to show a line breaks.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, I tried your code and got:     elif fout is not None:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @PranavHosangadi that itself might be the reason why OP's code isn't working... Sophi, Does your file has line breaks after every values line...?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi false alarm! my bad

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, no it has no blank lines

Comment: @Sophi, what character is the error at? It runs fine for me

Comment: @Sophi it would be better if you could post the entire traceback with proper indentation....Try editing the error you are getting into your question and don't forget to enclose it inside back ticks : ```  ```

Comment: @ Yatin, please see above the new code which gives complains about " elif fout is not None"

Comment: @Sophi, I looked at your suggested edit. You don't need the extra for loop or anything. Your entire `for k in range(24):...` loop from the question should be replaced by mine and it works fine

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, but I need to place every file in a separate directory, if I remove the for loop how can I make those directories?

Comment: When you see a line that says "timestep", you want to create a directory and open a new file inside that directory. That's what the `# insert code to make new directory` did. You were supposed to add your directory code there because I was too lazy to copy it in from the question. I've edited my answer to include it now.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, in your new code we have "path = os.path.join(BaseDir, 'steps_{0:01d}'.format(k))" but we have not defined "k", so how the code knows about "k" without for loop?

Comment: @Sophi It should be `timestepnum` instead of `k`